# How can action be triggered on any mouse button event?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

For this I don't actually write any program, but I would like to understand how it is implemented in JS to countermeasure it.

I know about `onclick`, `onmousedown`, `onmouseup` and `ondblclick`. I **block** those events for page, using such rules (Privoxy; simple text replacement):

```
s@onclick=@noclick=@gi
s@onmousedown=@nomousedown=@gi
s@onmouseup=@nomouseup=@gi
s@ondblclick=@nodblclick=@gi
```

*I know it is pretty crude, it is not the point here.*

Yet the page still reacts to mouse events and when I click on static text it gives me a lot of popups and popunders.

So, is there another mouse button event in Javascript? What tricks can be applied to JS to avoid those 4 filters?

Comment: You can add many handlers to the same event using `addEventListener`, which is probably how the ones you're experiencing were attached

Comment: Thank you, could you please post it as answer, not comment (I cannot accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with adding event handlers as attributes in *HTML* and properties of *HTMLElements* in *JavaScript*, you can also use *JavaScript* to attach a handler to an element using [`HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), which lets you attach many handlers for the same event.

This way of attaching the handler is most likely the one which is bypassing your current blocks, and could be difficult to remove.

---

One way to bypass it could be (this must execute before the line you want to prevent)

```
HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = (function (listen) {
    return function (a) {
        if (a === 'click') // for example
            return;
        return listen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}(HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener));
```

Answer (score 0):

These following mouse events are in JavaScript :

**mousedown**, user depresses the mouse button on this element

**mouseup**, user releases the mouse button on this element

**click**, one **mousedown** and one **mouseup** detected on this element

**dblclick**

**mousemove**

**mouseover and mouseout**

For More Refrence : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html